# making a (key,value) rdd from two lists

Tags: python, apache-spark, rdd

I have to make a (key,value) rdd from two lists such that keys are from `list1` and values are from `list2`. Suppose the two lists are:
`list1=[1,2,3] , list2=[4,5,6]`. My rdd sould be:

```
[(1,4),(2,5),(3,6)]
```

Here is my approach of doing it:

```
list1=[1,2,3]
list2=[4,5,6]
list3=[]
for i in range(0,3):
    v=[list1[i],list2[i]].append(list3)
rdd=sc.parallize(list3)
```

but not getting the output. Any help would be grateful. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: list comprehension? `{x:y for (x,y) in zip([1,2,3], [4,5,6])}`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `zip`:

```
list(zip(list1, list2))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use following instead :

```
list1=[1,2,3]
list2=[4,5,6]
list3 = dict(zip(list1,list2))
rdd=sc.parallize(list3)
```